# React native style on View or Text in map rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I am watching a tutorial that says In React Native that to render a list of items you use the map function (nothing new, I know react) But he says that I should return a View element which has a Text Element inside it which holds my content. Example :

```
<View>
        {list.map((elem) => {
          return (
            <View>
            <Text key={Math.random()} >
              {elem}
            </Text>
           </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
```

He said because view lets us use more styling features than text. But I wrote a different code in which I returned a Text Directly, applied styles to it, and worked ok.

```
<View>
        {list.map((elem) => {
          return (
            <Text key={Math.random()} style={styles.text}>
              {elem}
            </Text>
          );
        })}
      </View>
```

So should I return a `<View><Text>{elemenet}</Text></View>` or just directly `<Text>{element}</Text>`

Answer (score 0):

The `<View>` and `<Text>` components in React Native accept similar `style` values but there is some difference between them. In general, both components work the same for almost everything but the `<Text>` has specific keys for styling text as it is intended to be used for that.

You can read more about it directly at the official docs:

- [`<Text>` style](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props) that states the type of the prop can be [`TextStyles`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props) or [`ViewStyles`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props)
- [`<View>` style](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#style) that states the type of it is just [`ViewStyles`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props)

In addition to that, there is a "conceptual" use for both components and a fallback for Native elements. It is a similar comparison to be made as:

- `<View>` is the equivalent of `<div>`
- `<Text>` is the equivalent of `<span>`

So, if you want a sequence of "blocks" of text stacked vertically as a "List" of something, use `<View>` wrapping your `<Text>` elements.

I also noticed that you added the `key` prop to the `<Text>` and not the outer `<View>` component, with the `Math.random()`. You can use the `elem.id` or some unique id generator instead (thanks to @Kipnoedels for mentioning that and providing [this link](https://robinpokorny.com/blog/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern/)!) with some text such as this:

```
<View>
  {list.map((elem) => (
    <View key={`shopping-element-${elem.id}`}>
      <Text>
        {elem}
      </Text>
    </View>
  )}
</View>
```

Comment: I am new to React, and even though I know CSS and React, I need more focus because flexbox is active on View Component(correct me if I am wrong). Is it better to return <View><Text>{elemenet}</Text></View> or just directly <Text>{element}</Text> in the list of items?

Comment: Just want to point out that you should *never* use an index as key in react if you have other options! Keys are also used to identify a component, which can break your application. Use a static id or string instead. Read more here: https://robinpokorny.com/blog/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern/ 

In this case a key could be `shopping-element-${elem.id}`.

Comment: I think I answered: It depends. In general, most of the cases (and probably your case) wrap it in a `<View>`. I also provided links and explanations but: the `style` prop from the `<Text>` accepts **all the keys from the `<View>`** + the ones exclusively for styling texts (read more at the links about the types TextStyles and ViewStyles). So, the short answer is: Yes, wrap it with `<View>`.

Comment: And yes, as @Kipnoedels mentioned: I suggest using the `elem.id` or some unique id generator instead of the index. Thanks for that!